# Compute the value of the complex integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

If $a\in \mathbb C$ with $|a|<1$ then find the value of the integration: $$\dfrac{1-|a|^{2}}{\pi}\int_{|z|=1} \dfrac{|dz|}{|z+a|^{2}}.$$

I can't proceed anyway, my main difficulty is for $|dz|.$

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: I believe the $|dz|$ is some kind of typo, is it a homework question?

Comment: First time I see $|dz|$. Where did you get this ? A book ?

Comment: It is neither a homework question nor get in a book. It is a question of 'GATE-2014' (an Indian competitive examination for P.hd.).

Comment: I have a feeling that the notation $|dz|$ means that if we parametrize $\{|z| = 1\}$ by $\varphi: [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb C, t \mapsto e^{i\varphi}$, then we have the "usual" substitution $dz = \frac{d\varphi}{dt}dt$, but also the substitution $|dz| = |\frac{d\varphi}{dt}dt| = |\frac{d\varphi}{dt}|dt.$ We can pull $dt$ out of the $|\cdot|,$ because t is strictly increasing.

Comment: [continued] This is related to the fact that for a smooth curve $\Gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb C,$ defined on $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb R,$ we have $\int_\Gamma |dz| = TotalVariation(\Gamma) = ArcLength(\Gamma).$ Unfortunately, I can't find a good online reference for that.

Comment: I know that $\int_{\gamma} |dz|=Arc Length(\gamma)$. But how we compute the integral & what is the value of it? Please give details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z=e^{i \phi} \implies dz = i e^{i \phi} d\phi \implies |dz| = d\phi - -i dz/z$$

$$|z+a|^2 = (z+a) (\bar{z} + \bar{a})  = |z|^2 + \bar{a} z+a \bar{z} + |a|^2 = 1+|a|^2+  \bar{a} z + a z^{-1}$$

Then the integral is

$$-i \frac{1-|a|^2}{\pi} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{\bar{a} z^2 + (1+|a|^2) z + a} $$

Now find the poles

$$z_{\pm} = \frac{-(1+|a|^2) \pm (1-|a|^2)}{2 \bar{a}} = \begin{cases}-a & + \\ -1/\bar{a} & - \end{cases}$$

We only need the residue at the pole $z_+$ (since $|a| \lt 1$), which is $1/(1-|a|^2)$.  Thus, by the Residue Theorem, the integral is

$$-i \frac{1-|a|^2}{\pi} i 2 \pi \frac1{1-|a|^2} = 2$$

Comment: Why $|dz|=d\phi$ & $|dz|\not=|d\phi|$ why not?

Comment: @Panja.S.: the contour is always defined in a positive sense so that $d\phi = |dz|$ here.

Comment: So, without changing the variable by putting $z=e^{i\phi}$ if we write just $|dz|=dz$ & find it's poles then it is clear. So ,I think your first line is unnecessary in the proof. Am I right?